# IE - problems with caching

Tags: internet-explorer, caching

Can somebody tell me why i have to clear the cache of the internet explorer to get the latest data from the database? I only have this problem with ie when i'm looking on a website. In the offline mode i have to start the debug mode to get the lastest data from the database. If i switch off the debug mode i have the same problem as online.

The problem is only with div and iframe. and i use php. so ie doesn't show me the latetst information in div or iframe. Only when i clear the cache.

I also switch off the automatical pre-caching.

What can i do.

Comment: There probably is an easy answer, but I've found that caching is one of those dark arts that involve many factors, some seemingly unrelated.  One of the best resources I've found are the related posts on @EricLaw's old IEInternals blog  (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/tags/caching/).

Answer (score 0):

You can always force to disable caching by setting the Caching Directives to "no-cache".

> PHP scripts often generate dynamic content that must not be cached by
>   the client browser or any proxy caches between the server and the
>   client browser. Many proxies and clients can be forced to disable
>   caching with:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php